# remove row from data frame and the keep the row numbering sequenced

Tags: r, dataframe, row, subset

I am trying to remove a row from a data frame, and I want keep the row numbering in order after removing the row. For example, if I remove row #208 the numbering goes like 207, 209, 210, instead of desired 207, 208, 209.

Here is an example of the code:

```
for(i in 1:210) {
DataFrame_remove<-DataFrame[-c(i),]
}
```

Here is the data frame after removing row #210

```
              Date         Q     LogQ  ConcLow ConcHigh Uncen  ConcAve Julian Month Day  DecYear MonthSeq        SinDY         CosDY
    207 2008-03-01 236.34381 5.465288  6.81600  6.81600     1  6.81600  57768     3  61 2008.165     1899  0.861701760  5.074151e-01
    208 2008-04-01 195.61188 5.276132  5.33200  5.33200     1  5.33200  57799     4  92 2008.250     1900  1.000000000  3.835054e-13
    209 2008-05-01  48.07530 3.872769  2.32000  2.32000     1  2.32000  57829     5 122 2008.332     1901  0.870285241 -4.925481e-01
    211 2008-07-01  14.15844 2.650311  0.02600  0.02600     1  0.02600  57890     7 183 2008.499     1903  0.008583481 -9.999632e-01
    212 2008-08-01  14.89806 2.701231  0.17600  0.17600     1  0.17600  57921     8 214 2008.583     1904 -0.500000000 -8.660254e-01
    213 2008-09-01  16.97604 2.831803  0.34700  0.34700     1  0.34700  57952     9 245 2008.668     1905 -0.870285241 -4.925481e-01
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `row.names(DataFrame_remove) <- NULL`.  You don't need a loop to remove some rows. `DateFrame[-(208:212),]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @akrun in the comments, you can do this with a simple `rownames(your_data_frame) <- NULL` *and* you can drop the rows much more directly:

Here's an example:

First, some sample data:

```
x <- data.frame(matrix(1:14, ncol = 2))
toRemove <- 3:5
```

Second, dropping the rows--the gap is still there:

```
out <- x[-toRemove, ]
out
#   X1 X2
# 1  1  8
# 2  2  9
# 6  6 13
# 7  7 14
```

Third, resetting the sequence of row numbers:

```
rownames(out) <- NULL
out
#   X1 X2
# 1  1  8
# 2  2  9
# 3  6 13
# 4  7 14
```

---

However, there is a more direct approach: use `"rownames<-"` (with quotes, or backticks), like this...

```
`rownames<-`(x[-toRemove, ], NULL)
#   X1 X2
# 1  1  8
# 2  2  9
# 3  6 13
# 4  7 14
```